# how to manage database in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, multi-database

i want to use multiple databases, i have **1db/user** and 1 main db,already set main db in config file but how to manage user database(**db name =  {user_id}_db**). thanks in advance

this is my config code

```
'main' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: every time new user register i'm   creating new db

Comment: For all users there will be different databases?

Comment: 1 main db for auth and setup and 1 db par user

Comment: creating DB for each user is useless, even if you are doing it for security or any other purpose whatsoever. useful SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721772/mysql-performance-multiple-tables-vs-index-on-single-table-and-partitions#answer-16768830 your question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel#answer-31847198

Comment: this not useless, i have 10000+order/min and all user have it own custom product

Comment: please read up on that SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721772/mysql-performance-multiple-tables-vs-index-on-single-table-and-partitions#answer-16768830. it's not advisable to create multiple databases. but if you insist, then close one connection to database and connect to another database connection. but you need to have config in .env file as well as config/database.php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel#answer-31847198

Answer (score 0):

Creating DB for each user is useless, even if you are doing it for security or any other purpose whatsoever. Useful SO link [MySQL performance: multiple tables vs. index on single table and partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721772/mysql-performance-multiple-tables-vs-index-on-single-table-and-partitions#answer-16768830)

Your question (connecting to multiple databases in Laravel) is already answered here. [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel#answer-31847198)

**UPDATE**

I guess, you want to create new databases on the fly and connect to them (without using .env configuration). Create dynamic connections instead of specifying  'connection-name' when trying to connect to a new database. Then, using `Config::set` you can create new temporary connections and then use `DB::connection` with the temporary name you just created. read more https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel#answer-31847198 this not I'm looking for, in this answered he use Multiple Database Connections which already define but i don't have any connection or can say it is not possible to define connection in config file

Answer (score 0):

You can use following configuration for multiple dbs.

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # primary 
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'ip1',
            'database'  => 'db1',
            'username'  => 'user',
            'password'  => 'pwd'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # secondary db connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'dbip2',
            'database'  => 'db2',
            'username'  => 'user',
            'password'  => 'pwd'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null
        ),
        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/db.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then you can use the the connection() method:

```
$connection = ‘mysql2’;

Schema::connection($connection)->create(function(Blueprint $table) {

//

});
```

Comment: OK i found solution, just use user_id as prefix and create dynamic connection and it's working nicely.