# MySql table with and without partition performance issues

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, partitioning

We have a reporting data table which will have millions of records. The data will be added in the table incrementally. To make the data fetch and insert optimal. Currently we have around 100K test data rows for 1 company and 10 users and in the table.

We are testing different options.

1. apply separate index to columns company_id , user_id. (Query execution time: 687ms)
2. apply combine index for columns (company_id, user_id). (Query execution time: 1.1s)
3. apply partition with primary (company_id, user_id, id) and two individual indexes on company_id and user_id. (Query execution time: 2.6s)

We have attached the table and "Explain" query results in the ticket.

In theory the partition results shall be optimal then the normal index but as you can see in the results below, the number of rows traverse for partition is much more higher than without partition and we are guessing that this is main reason for the
slow performance in partitions.

We have followed this link [partition reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721772/mysql-performance-multiple-tables-vs-index-on-single-table-and-partitions) for understanding and applying the partition.

Can someone please guide us whether the partition really necessary for huge amount of data e.g. 30 million records OR the index will be okay?

(1)

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sensor` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_group` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_c_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `idx_u_id` (`user_id`)
) 


EXPLAIN 
select company_id, department, sum(value) as result  
from table1 
where company_id = 55 
  and user_id in (127, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133) 
  and (time_group between '2024-01-01 00:00:00' and '2024-01-30 23:59:59') 
group by sensor
order by result desc;
```

[Query Explain Result without partition, with individual indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnKSN.png)

(2)

[Query Explain Result without partition, with combined index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxqQl.png)

(3)

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sensor` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_group` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`, `user_id`, `id`),
  KEY `idx_id` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_c_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `idx_u_id` (`user_id`)
) PARTITION BY HASH(company_id) PARTITIONS 11;


EXPLAIN 
select company_id, department, sum(value) as result  
from table2 
where company_id = 55 
  and user_id in (127, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133) 
  and (time_group between '2024-01-01 00:00:00' and '2024-01-30 23:59:59') 
group by sensor
order by result desc;
```

[Query Explain Result with partition and individual indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKqEY.png)

[Query Explain Result with partition and combined indexes (company_id,user_id,time_group)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVZRT.png)

we have followed the solution provided in this [partition reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721772/mysql-performance-multiple-tables-vs-index-on-single-table-and-partitions). But Result is reletively slow with partition as compared to simple indexed as explained above. Are we missing something?

Furthermore, Indexes sizes with partitions are big.

```
SELECT 
    database_name, 
    table_name, 
    index_name,
    ROUND(stat_value * @@innodb_page_size / 1024 / 1024, 2) size_in_mb
FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats
WHERE stat_name = 'size' 
  AND index_name != 'PRIMARY' 
  and database_name = 'db'
ORDER BY size_in_mb DESC;
```

[Index sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUQIp.png)

Mysql version:
[MySql version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzq3Y.png)

Comment: The result of the explain isn't readable , pleas use text and please format the query that we can read it without scrolling

Comment: Also use a combined index with all three columns in the where clause

Comment: `select company_id ... where company_id = 55 ... group by company_id ...` [censored]

Comment: A correct answer depends on a lot of questions which are not answers by the question.  How many company_id's will you have (1 or 10000)? How many user_id's will you have (10 or 10.000.000)? How long will you keep the data (1 month, 6 months, 12 months, 7 year)?

Comment: Can you please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Luuk, sorry for the inconvenience. I update the question details and answer your questions. Thank you for informing me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GROUP BY company_id` when you also have `WHERE company_id = 55`.  *If, instead, you remove the `=55`, all the index and partition discussion (so far) is incorrect!.*

For `table1`, I recommend this without PARTITIONing:

```
ADD TABLE table2
    DROP INDEX `idx_c_id`,   -- in the way
    ADD INDEX(company_id, user_id);
```

`table2` already has the equivalent via the PK.

(See also my [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) blog.)

If (and only if) most of your activity is really on month boundaries, then `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(time_group)) ...` and

```
ADD TABLE table2
    DROP INDEX `idx_c_id`;   -- in the way
```

I recommend this formulation of the "month" range.  (No performance difference; just other benefits)

```
     time_group >= '2024-01-01'
 AND time_group  < '2024-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: "GROUP BY company_id" was a mistake during question preparation. so I corrected it in the question details. Method you are recommending without partitioning, we tried and mentioned as 2nd point in question details, but if you look at the Explain query screenshot, the index(company_id, user_id) is not being used and searched rows count is equal to the total rows exist for company_id = 55 and 10 users, but I am querying for only 6 users.

Comment: I can not use Hash on time_group because our activities are not on month boundaries, but on a single date to a whole month. I have added a screenshot of the MySql version.

Comment: I have also added a screenshot of "Query Explain Partition".

Comment: When the PK is `(complany_id, ...)`, do not also have `INDEX(company_id)`.